# how to add headers with rest call in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch-2.1

I am new to sencha development. so I don't know how to parse rest API calls in sencha?
If any one knows please help me?

example:
HTTP Method - GET
HTTP Headers
· Accept application/xml,application/json
· Authorization
· User-Agent

I want to this header with request, how to do this in sencha? Please explain with example friends. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since REST uses ajax proxy so i believe this should work. Bind **beforerequest** event as soon as app is launched, such that it adds certain headers to any AJAX request

```
Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', function(conn, options, eOptions){
        options.headers['Authorization'] = 'BASIC YTpi';
}, this);
```

If you have headers which don't change you can even do this:

```
    Ext.Ajax._defaultHeaders = {
        'Accept': 'application/xml,application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic YTpi'
    };
```

**PS** I have not used it for REST so please verify before using.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but is it possible to do the same for jsonp, or at least something similar? I tried it for my jsonp proxies but it didn't work.